# How to list all I/O ports in windows/linux?

Tags: port, io

We can use `netstat` to list all software ports,but how to list all hardware ports,is there such a tool?

Answer (score 5):

Under Linux:

```
cat /proc/ioports
```

Answer (score 2):

To view how your computer has assigned your I/O addresses open Device Manager,

1. click **View** at the top of the Device Manager window
2. click **Resources by type**, and then select Input/Output (IO).

This should give you an output similar to the picture shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well, they are 'different' ports - tcp ports are more in terms of IO than actual ports (USB, PCI slots ect)

If you want hardware information you can use lshw or (i believe ) dmidecode. If you want to know what's going on in terms of I/O in general you can use iotop

Comment: Does `dmidecode` show information about the port number of a device?

Comment: Not that kind of port.